# Slimming down video playlist code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how I go about slimming down the code i've produced for a video player. Every time I add a new video I am having to copy the function for each and replicate it for the relevant one. Does anyone know how to trim this down so that when I add a new video to the list it will appropriate the correct function to display it, without having to copy, paste and just change the links.

Fiddle is here - http://jsfiddle.net/olichalmers/44tQM/

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

        var videoContainer = $('.video-hold');
        var videoOneBtn = $('.one');
        var videoTwoBtn = $('.two');
        var videoThreeBtn = $('.three');
        var videoFourBtn = $('.four');

        var videoOne = '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/brFKqr0BZcE?wmode=transparent&controls=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>';
        var videoTwo = '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/wxrYmYyRMZk?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>';
        var videoThree = '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/MaCSd0eD5Rw?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>';
        var videoFour = '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/MaCSd0eD5Rw?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>';


        videoContainer.append(videoOne);


        videoOneBtn.click(function (e) {

            videoContainer.empty().append(videoOne);

                $('.video-hold iframe').each(function () {

                    var url = $(this).attr("src");

                    $(this).attr("src", url + "&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0");

                    return false;

                });

                e.preventDefault();
        });




        videoTwoBtn.click(function (e) {

            videoContainer.empty().append(videoTwo);

            $('.video-hold iframe').each(function () {

                var url = $(this).attr("src");

                $(this).attr("src", url + "&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0");

                return false;

            });

            e.preventDefault();

        });




        videoThreeBtn.click(function (e) {

            videoContainer.empty().append(videoThree);

            $('.video-hold iframe').each(function () {

                var url = $(this).attr("src");

                $(this).attr("src", url + "&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0");

                return false;

            });

            e.preventDefault();

        });




        videoFourBtn.click(function (e) {

            videoContainer.empty().append(videoFour);

            $('.video-hold iframe').each(function () {

                var url = $(this).attr("src");

                $(this).attr("src", url + "&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0");

                return false;

            });

            e.preventDefault();

        });



});
```

Best,
Oliver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the following: in your HTML, change the classes you have in an id, and add a class, like this:

```
        <li><a href="#" class="vidbtn" id="one">Paper Heart</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="vidbtn"  id="two">Rumour</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="vidbtn"  id="three">Millionaire Transmitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="vidbtn"  id="four">Another video</a></li>
```

and if you have this, you can execute the function once like this:

```
$( ".vidbtn" ).click(function(e ) {
        videoContainer.empty().append(eval(this.id));

            $('.video-hold iframe').each(function () {

                var url = $(this).attr("src");

                $(this).attr("src", url + "&autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0");

                return false;

            });

            e.preventDefault();

        });
```

hope this will help you.

EDIT:

Here's a working JSFiddle based on your code with some changes:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/applepie89/q85a4/)

Comment: Vincent thanks a lot pal, this looks great and was exactly what I was looking for. Best.

Comment: Sorry it took me a while, I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option that could get you started:

Add the src value to each anchor tag and use a shared classname:

```
<li><a href="#" class="videoBtn" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/brFKqr0BZcE?
wmode=transparent&controls=0&showinfo=0">Paper Heart</a></li>
```

Then you can simply bind to `$('videoBtn').click()`.

In the function, use `$(this).attr("src")` so you can build the url you want:

```
var video = '<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="' 
            + $(this).attr("src") 
            + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>';
```

And place that wherever you want it.

By this method you can accomplish the same with just one function to handle all the links.